# how to disable pasting in one of the gwt textbox

Tags: gwt, textbox, event-handling, uibinder, onpaste

I have two textboxes and i want to just disable one of them from pasting anything. I have tried

```
 sinkEvents( Event.ONPASTE );
```

but it disables both of the textboxes from pasting.

Comment: Are you calling sinkEvents on one of the two textboxes?

Comment: sinkEvents by itself shouldn't disable either one - what else are you doing, and what are you calling sinkEvents on?

Comment: @Fedy2 : I am calling sinEvents in my uibinders view class constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Try to create a custom `TextBox` wherein you have to override `onBrowserEvent` function.

```
public TextInput() {
    super();

    sinkEvents( Event.ONPASTE );
}

@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
    super.onBrowserEvent( event );

    switch (DOM.eventGetType(event)) {
        case Event.ONPASTE:
            event.preventDefault();
            break;
    }
}
```